# MYSQL fill group by "gaps"

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I´m trying to fill the gaps after using group by using an aux table, can you help?

**aux table to deal with days with no orders**

```
date        quantity
2014-01-01  0
2014-01-02  0
2014-01-03  0
2014-01-04  0
2014-01-05  0
2014-01-06  0
2014-01-07  0
```

**group by result from "orders" table**

```
date        quantity
2014-01-01  7
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-04  2
2014-01-05  3
```

**desired result joining "orders" table with "aux table"**

```
date        quantity
2014-01-01  7
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-03  0
2014-01-04  2
2014-01-05  3
2014-01-06  0
2014-01-07  0
```

Comment: What query is producing your `group by result`?  I think you need to use an `outer join` with those results to your `aux` table if I'm understanding your question correctly.  Your sample data is a little misleading...

Comment: my problem is with outer join.. the "dates" table is already created as "aux table"

Comment: yes, outer join the group by result with aux table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how you create your `group by result` table, what you're looking for in an `outer join`, perhaps with `coalesce`.  Something like this:

```
select distinct a.date, coalesce(b.quantity,0) quantity
from aux a 
    left join yourgroupbyresults b on a.date = b.date
```

Please note, you may or may not need `distinct` -- depends on your data.

---

Edit, given your comments, this should work:

```
select a.date, count(b.date_sent)
from aux a
    left join orders b on a.date = date_format(b.date_sent, '%Y-%m-%d')
group by a.date
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3958ba/1)

Comment: my group by is from: select date_format(date_sent, '%Y-%m-%d'), count(*) as quantity from orders

Answer (score 1):

Using your results it would be something like:

```
SELECT a.date
      ,COALESCE(b.quantity,0) as quantity
FROM auxtable a
LEFT JOIN groupbyresult b
  ON a.date = b.date
```

You can also do your grouping in the same query as the left join:

```
SELECT a.date
      ,COALESCE(COUNT(b.somefield),0) as quantity
FROM auxtable a
LEFT JOIN table1 b
  ON a.date = b.date
GROUP BY a.date
```

Answer (score 0):

One familiar approach to solving a problem like this is to use a row source that has the distinct list of dates you want to return, and then do an outer join to the table that has gaps. That way, you get all the dates back, and you can substitute a zero for the "missing" quantity values.

For example:

```
SELECT d.date
     , IFNULL(SUM(s.quantity),0) AS quantity
  FROM distinct_list_of_dates d
  LEFT
  JOIN information_source s
    ON s.date = d.date
 GROUP BY d.date
```

It's not clear why a GROUP BY would be eliminating some date values. We might conjecture that you are using a MySQL extension to ANSI-standard GROUP BY semantics, and that is eliminating rows. Or, you may have a WHERE clause that is excluding rows. But we're just guessing.

---

**FOLLOW UP** based on further information revealed by OP in comments...

In the query above, replace `distinct_list_of_dates` with `aux`, and replace `information_source` with `orders`, and adjusting the join predicate to account for datetime comparison to date

```
SELECT d.date
     , IFNULL(SUM(s.quantity),0) AS quantity
  FROM aux d
  LEFT
  JOIN orders s
    ON s.date >= d.date
   AND s.date <  d.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP BY d.date
```

Comment: . . I think you missed that the first table *does* have the list of dates.

Comment: ... @GordonLinoff: it's impossible to tell what is causing the behavior OP is observing. The answer I gave is a general approach to the general problem of sparse data. In OP example the distinct_list_of_dates row source may indeed be the `aux` table, or an inline view `(SELECT a.date FROM aux a GROUP BY a.date)`. Absent an actual specification, we're just guessing. (If OP query is doing a `GROUP BY some_foo`, we'd expect that some `date` values might be missing from the result.